# What are the key differences in batting strategies and shot selection between Test cricket, One Day Internationals (ODIs),T20 matches?

Tags: cricket, strategy, icc

How do shot selection, strategies adopted, and the approach of the team differ in Test, one-day games, and T20 formats of cricket? How do they adapt to these conditions and play according to the conditions?